# How to make colons optional in a regex search for a number

Tags: regex

I am trying to pull out a specific number from a text string using regex in UIPATH. The regex works in every case where there is not a colon in the text.

I am searching for the word `EWO` (with or without a `:`). i.e. `EWO` or `EWO:`
I then require the 6 numbers which come after this word.

I have used the following up until I discovered there could be a colon:
Text to search

```
TEST0203033 EWO 125399 WWT US QUOTE# 1235338.1
```

or

```
TEST0203033 EWO: 125399 WWT US QUOTE# 1235338.1
```

I have tried adding a `:?` to make the colon in the search optional, but get strange responses back.

In the String `TEST0203033 EWO: 125399 WWT US QUOTE# 1235338.1`

using

```
(?<=EWO:?\s*)([0-9]+)
```

results `: 12`

Where I was expecting the result `125399`

Original, does not work with colon

```
(?<=EWO\s*)([0-9]+)
```

Produces some weird results

```
(?<=EWO:?\s*)([0-9]+)
```

Comment: Use `EWO:?\s*([0-9]+)` and get Group 1 value. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/RVwMxU/1). What is the tool/programming language?

Comment: If it is Python, `EWO:?\s*([0-9]+)` is what OP needs, no need to play with lookbehinds. However, I see that it is actually .NET based. So, `(?<=EWO:?\s*)[0-9]+` must work.

Comment: Wiktor i think that InterSimi whats for the Regex to work for both "EWO" or "EWO:" scenarios. That is why i suggested @InterSimi `((?<=EWO\s)[0-9]+|(?<=EWO:\s)[0-9]+)`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I have tried your example, but am not sure how to pull 'Group 1' The result comes back as "EWO: 125399", so includes the text and the colon

Comment: Konstantinos, your option worked for me, thank you. I don't know how to mark it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/UOyWPk/1) might help to divide your target inputs into two separate groups, where you can simply call the desired number with `$2`:

```
([EWO\:]+)\s([0-9]+)
```

[image]

You can also further simplify it by removing group `$1`, or create an exact match similar to [this](https://regex101.com/r/WyvSHz/1/):

```
(TEST[0-9]+\s)[EWO\:\s]+([0-9]+)\sWWT\sUS\sQUOTE#\s([0-9\.]+)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it in Java but the regex pattern should be the same for most engines.

```
      String text1 = "TEST0203033 EWO 125399 WWT US QUOTE# 1235338.1";
      String text2 = "TEST0203033 EWO: 125399 WWT US QUOTE# 1235338.1";

      // Find EWO with an optional : following by 0 or more spaces.
      // Then capture the number.
      String regx = "EWO:? *(\\d+)";

      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regx);

      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text1);
      if (matcher.find()) {
         System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
      }

      matcher.reset(text2);
      if (matcher.find()) {
         System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
      }
```